# boot failure: wrong mount point (Kubuntu)

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, live-cd

I tried to make an external luks encrypted drive (like i did several times). I was then unable to write to said drive and tried to change permissions (but of course could not remember how to do it). I failed at that task.
During my tries i changed the mount point of the external drive. Unfortunately it seems to have changed the mount point for the other drives as well (I assume). As i restarted the computer it was unable to boot
It used to be: media/USERNAME and now it tries to go to: media/usb
I get the error: timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-luks........

Unfortunately the advanced option menu does not work properly, it is overlayed with other messages, i wanted to reinstall kubuntu and keep my files, but it seems this is only possible in ubuntu

I am using the latest version of kubuntu.

If any more information is requiered please ask, i searched now for several hours and could not find a solution =/

glad for any help
kind regards
luke

Answer (score 1):

found the solution:

the problem was in fstab
because i was stressed i did look for it in the wrong place
with a kubuntu installation usb drive i was able to boot in the try-it-out version and then i could mount the drive
then wen to the "root" drive (which confusingly contais a "root" folder which is locked, but turnes out i don't need that one anyway)
in that folder is the "etc" folder in which is a "fstab.txt" 
I checked with partition manager what "UUID-number" the boot-drive has, i also remembered from the error message and from mounting the external-drive (which i mentioned in my question) the UUID-number of said drive
i uncommented ("#" in front of everything) whatever was added in the last line because there was the number of the external-drive and further up was the uuid-number of the boot-drive
restarted and everything was fine

=)